# Why is Sencha Cmd not compiling my custom sass files

Tags: extjs, sass, sencha-cmd

UPDATE - when I put the file here, it works, the scss file is compiled into a css file.

```
\workspace\packages\amc-custom-theme\sass\etc\extra.scss
```

But a line in index.html referencing the new css file is not added. How do I make that happen?

I'm starting to use Sencha Cmd. I put a custom sass file here:

```
\workspace\extApps\MyApp\sass\etc\extra.scss
```

But it is not being compiled into the AMC-all.css file.

For now this is the contents of the scss file:

```
@import 'compass';

.actionColumnIcon {
    margin-right: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Its just a test. But I need it to work to continue.

Answer (score 1):

Try `sass/all.scss` instead of `sass/extra.scss`.

Comment: But why does not pick all scss?